# Speed dating/networking challenge

Tags: probability-distributions, algorithms, contest-math

I am trying to organise an event with 54 participants.

I want them to participate in 9 different activities at stations around a hall. Obviously this will require 9 sessions to allow the participants to visit each station.

I would also like the participants in groups of 6 at each station.

The problem arises from the fact that I would also like to use this as a networking opportunity. It would be great if someone knew of a method or algorithm to allocate participants to groups so that they only meet other participants once. Two encounters would be acceptable but I don't really want any more than that.

Does anyone know of an algorithm or methodology that would help to produce a timetable?

Thanks
          - Matt

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman's_schoolgirl_problem

Comment: I think it is not related the group theory.

Comment: Thanks athos. I never knew that combinatorics was a thing. My problem has slightly larger numbers but the principle should see me right.

Comment: Aaghh!! I'm such a loser. I gave up and just allocated slots to the individuals manually.